# Управление файлами в django через html

Tags: python, html, django

Сделал калькулятор на python, хочу его запускать через html шаблон в django, при нажатии кнопки старт он открывается, и появляется input поле, куда нужно ввести первое число затем выбрать действие сложить или вычесть, потом ввести второе число и получить ответ, в шаблон передаётся вся информация для input поля, но я не знаю как реализовать отправку команд в запущено приложения, у меня получается только отправлять команды в терминал подскажите пожалуйста, что можно придумать?

```
def test(request):
    if 'activation_key' in request.session:
        #поддерживаем сессию если авторизован
        key = request.session['activation_key']
        if request.method == "POST" and 'start' in request.POST:
            #если нажата кнопка старт
            start = request.POST.get('start', False)
            print("запущено")
            #пропишем команду и путь до файла
            script = 'python C:\\Users\\kato-pc\\Desktop\\rad\\mysite\\test.py > C:\\Users\\kato-pc\\Desktop\\rad\\mysite\\text.txt'
            #os.system(script)
            #выпоним команду в терминале
            subprocess.Popen(script, shell=True)
            f = open('C:\\Users\\kato-pc\\Desktop\\rad\\mysite\\text.txt', 'r')
            line = f.read().splitlines()[-1]
            return redirect('/main/test', {'start': start, 'output': line})
        if request.method == "POST" and 'command' in request.POST:
            # если нажата кнопка отправить
            input = request.POST.get('command')

            #берём открытый процесс
            
            #принимаем значение из переменной input и отправляем его в этот процесс



            print("нажал")
            return redirect('/main/test', {'output1': input})
            
        return render(request, 'main/test.html', parm)
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: как тоу вас все сложно

Comment: попробуйте сделать форму ввода чисел и операции, а при нажатии кнопки рендерить шаблон с рзеультатом

Comment: Она уже рендериться, а при отправке формы нужно сделать отправку команды в открытое приложение на сервер через форму input которое имеет name- command